# Counting images in a horizontal image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/51tqf1v9/16/

My problem what's happening in the browser:
Images not resized to the browser's height (I want it without the scrollbar), but works in the Fiddle.

How I can count this loop?

```
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
function resize() {
  var windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - 17 + 'px';
  var imgList = document.getElementsByClassName('resize');

  for (i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    imgList[i].style.height = windowHeight;
  }

  alert('resize event detected!');
}
```

If I use the following, only the first image resized to the viewport's height (and still not without the horizontal scrollbar's height). The first image will be selected with this. I'm not a javascript programmer, I don't know how to create a working loop for all selected img elements:

```
window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
function resize() {
  var windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - 17 + 'px';
  var imgList = document.getElementsByClassName('resize');

  imgList[0].style.height = windowHeight;

  alert('resize event detected!');
}
```

I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

Thank You for your help!

Comment: so, what are you trying to do?

Comment: It seems to be working for me... can you clarify your issue?

Comment: It's working in JSFiddle, but not in local browsers (firefox, chrome). Images simply not will be resized. Horizontal and vertical images are presented in their native resolution. I want to resize them to the viewport's maximum height first (this is the actual problem), later calculating sizes according to the header's, footer's height (not part of this question).

Comment: This should work in local browsers too.

Comment: I added this css to remove the vertical scrollbar `html, body, div {
    height:100%;
}` You could then change the `div` for a more specific class.

Comment: do you have the class resize on all your images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `var` before `i`

use below code

```
    window.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
function resize() {
  var windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight + 'px';
  var imgList = document.getElementsByClassName('resize');

  for (var i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    imgList[i].style.height = windowHeight;
  }

  alert('resize event detected!');
}
```

using CSS

```
img.resize
{
    height:97vh;
}
```

Comment: It fixed, Thank You! It wasn't part of my question, but the scrollbar overflowing the screen. Do you know how to calculate the viewport height without the scrollbar? Seems like `window.document.documentElement.clientHeight` worked with div, but not with images.

Comment: It should work. **Try setting var windowHeight = (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight - 50) + 'px';**

Comment: Thank You! Is there an automatic solution maybe? Not extracting pixels, instead getting the calculated value?

Comment: Updated inline hopefully that should work. remove javascript code and include css

Comment: I tested this solution `.sidescroll .images img { height: calc(100vh - 17px); height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 17px); -moz-calc(100vh - 17px); }` Almost perfect, but if I shrink the browser's width to portrait phone size, the images are overlapping each other with a width of the browser viewport.

Comment: Solved by making horizontal scrolling the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just make all of the images have 100vh.

```
img
{
    100vh;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/51tqf1v9/14/